# Using ranges as keys in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, range, equality

I'm experimenting with using dictionaries in Python as an alternative to switch cases. I'd like to use a range of values as a key in my dictionary. I have something similar to the code below:

```
dispatcher = {
    0 < col_value <= .5: "avg",
    .5 < col_value <= .9: "value",
}

for col in self.missing_ratios_dict:

    self.to_do_list[col] = dispatcher.get(self.missing_ratios_dict[col], "drop")
```

missing_ratios_dict is a dictionary populated with pairs like "Age" : .199, "Name": 0.0, and so on.

What I would like for this to do is if the value of the column is between 0 and .5 to add "avg" to my to_do_list, if it's between .5 and .9 to add "value" to my to_do_list, and otherwise to add "drop" to my to_do_list.

Currently what it's actually doing is adding "value" if the value is 0.0 and "drop" otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dict` can not have hashable range as key. However, you may create a key denoting the range in the form of `tuple`, but it is of no use as you can not directly call `dict.get(x)` to get the value from key with tuple as `(y1, y2)` (where y1 < x keys to check if value is part of any range.

I will suggest you to create a function like this for finding the category:

```
def get_type(value):
    category = None
    if 0 < value < 0.5:
         category =  "avg"
    elif 0.5 <= value < 0.8:
         category = "good"
    return category
```